# How can I put several if statements into a Tkinter Button

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter

(edited)

I have tried to put my if statements into a messagebox function and have the button print out a message with a number and the corresponding player. I have tried everything I can think of and it still doesn't work, at the moment it prints out a random number but of course I want it to print the player's name as well, any help will be appreciated :)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import random


no_1 = "De Gea"
no_2 = "Lindelof"
no_3 = "Bailly"
no_5 = "Maguire"
no_6 = "Pogba"
no_7 = "Sancho"
no_8 = "Mata"
no_9 = "Martial"
no_10 = "Rashford"
no_12 = "Smalling"
no_13 = "Grant"
no_14 = "Lingard"
no_15 = "Pereira"
no_16 = "Rojo"
no_17 = "Fred"
no_18 = "Bruno"


def united_players():

    number = random.randint(1, 20)
    print(number)
    if number == 18:
        print(no_18)
    elif number == 17:
        print(no_17)
    elif number == 16:
        print(no_16)
    elif number == 15:
        print(no_15)
    elif number == 14:
        print(no_14)
    elif number == 13:
        print(no_13)
    elif number == 12:
        print(no_12)
    elif number == 10:
        print(no_10)
    elif number == 9:
        print(no_9)
    elif number == 8:
        print(no_8)
    elif number == 7:
        print(no_7)
    elif number == 6:
        print(no_6)
    elif number == 5:
        print(no_5)
    elif number == 3:
        print(no_3)
    elif number == 2:
        print(no_2)
    elif number == 1:
        print(no_1)
    else:
        print("Player not found")


def generate_number():
    messagebox.showinfo("You got this player!", random.randint(1, 20))


root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=600, width=600, bg="#e53242")
canvas.pack()

label1 = tk.Label(root, text="Click for a random player", bg="#e53242", fg="#323648")
label1.config(font=("", 24))
label1.place(relx=0.22, rely=0.1)

button1 = tk.Button(root, height=12, width=30, text="Random \n Man United player", command=generate_number, bg="#ef7a85", activebackground="#dd6d11")
button1.place(relx=0.34, rely=0.4)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you kindly recheck your code and paste it again? For example print(number) doesn't look like it has been declared as a function. And the elif argument for 15 seems to have another elif for 5 as well inside that? Is that intentional or?

Comment: Also include imports

Comment: Have you tried simply putting the code in a function, and calling the function from the button? It's not clear what you're really asking.

Comment: There are a few ways you can tackle this and a wall of `elif` is not the way. A function with a loop that goes through a list or a dictionary would be probably best.

Comment: Yep, and I already posted a solution. :)

Comment: I've added in the rest of my code. Yeah, I did try putting the code in a function and calling from the button but that didn't work and I think Scotty basically answered my question with a dictionary lookup so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case for a dictionary lookup:

```
players = {
    18: no_18, 17: no_17, 16: no_16, 15: no_15, 5: no_5,
    3: no_3, 2: no_2, 1: no_1}

def generate_number():
    messagebox.showinfo(
        "You got this player!", 
        players.get(random.randint(1, 20), 'Player not found!')
    )
```